# Why methods annotated with @BeforeAll and @AfterAll should be static in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, static, junit5

I know that methods annotated with `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` JUnit 5 annotations should be `static` unless `TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS` is used.

What I can't understand is *why* JUnit 5 imposes such limitations? If it is allowed with `PER_CLASS` lifecycle, what changes drastically when using `PER_METHOD`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `PER_METHOD`, a new instance of the test class is created for each test method. Methods annotated with `@BeforeAll` would need to be called before any instance is created. Likewise, `@AfterAll` needs to be called after all tests are done, and therefore no instance is available anymore. That lack of instances means these methods need to be static.